# Routing problems with Codeigniter and Backbone.js

Tags: .htaccess, backbone.js, requirejs, codeigniter-2

**Here are the frameworks I am using:**

- Codeigniter
- Codeigniter REST API
- Require.js
- Backbone.js

**Running the app:**

- The htaccess file redirects everything through the Codeigniter index.php file.
- There is a default route setup in Codeigniter to call the "Start" Controller.
- The Start Controller calls the Start View (the only view in Codeigniter ).
- The Start View holds the template for the entire website and makes a call to start Require.js
- Require.js starts up Backbone and app works as expected.

**Problem: Routing to other Backbone Views:**

- Now I want to route via Backbone to other Backbone "views".
- The problem is when I try to provide a link like "localhost/otherPage" in an HREF the htaccess file fires, and Codeigniter tries to find that controller and I get a 404 generated by Codeigniter.
- I have tried forcing a route in Backbone instead of HREF using `app.navigate("otherPage", {trigger: true});`, but I get the same 404 error generated by Codeigniter.

**What direction should I take:**

- I would like to continue to use Codeigniter for its RESTFUL API, Models and some special validation features.
- I also want to use Backbone and Require on the front end.
- Can I change the htacess redirect to an index.html file that fires up Require and Backbone.  Will the Codeigniter RESTFUL API Controllers still fire properly if I use this approach?
- Do I create a view in Codeigniter for each page and have each page start Require + Backbone a new for each view?
- I will be looking into Node.js very soon.  Should I just trash the Codeigniter aspect of the the framework and go whole hog on Node.js?

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're not already doing it, you may want to route via Backbone through the hashtag changes (it's his normal behavior, pushState: false), as modifying the hashtag would in no way result in a server call, thus ignoring Codeigniter's router.
In your example, you would want to navigate to *localhost/#otherPage*.
Then use Codeigniter's router for your ajax REST calls.

Comment: So do I trash my htaccess file and have a start.index file load Backbone?  When I make a call to the RESTFUL API in Codeigniter will the framework start up (with autoloads, etc) via the controller call?  This is the main problem I am having troubles understanding.

Comment: No you can still keep both of your routers as they don't work simultaneously: Backbone's router will handle hashtag changes (client-side, you're not making any call to the server), CodeIgniter will handle url changes (server-side, call to the server - certainly only your AJAX REST calls). Your REST calls will have to be routed by CodeIgniter (never used it) RESTFUL API.

Comment: @Lowkase The solution Loamhoof proposes is perfectly fine. To answer your question: the REST API calls to CodeIgniter will start up the framework's autoloads. Codeigniter won't differentiate between a GET request from your browser or from a Backbone .fetch(). The question is: why do you need to keep the CodeIgniter router? Dump the View part of Codeigniter's MVC, and substitute it entirely with Backbone's MV*. All routing is done by Backbone's router except the first call to start.index.html which bootstraps your RequireJs/Backbone.

Comment: @ThalisKalfigkopoulos That's exactly the info I needed.  Will do some work in the next couple of days to do as you and Loamhoof have proposed.  Stay tuned and thanks.

Comment: @ThalisKalfigkopoulos if his app is really big, both could be useful, but still, definitely worth wondering is codeigniter's one really needed.

Comment: @loamhoof Without having any hard evidence to back-it-up, I generally prefer to push functionality to the client i.e. passing it to Backbone, and leave at the server-side that stuff that inevitably has to stay there i.e. the real backend things such as the DB operations.

Comment: Thanks Loam and Thalis, going to award the bounty to this post.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to keep your browser from submitting the http request with the HREF link is to just override it with javascript and jquery. Could be useful if you don't want to always use hashtags as Loamhoof suggested.

Example:

```
$('#linkID').on('click', function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    backboneRouter.navigate($(event.currentTarget).attr('href'), { trigger:true });

});
```